# Modify JSON Data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a HTML Form from which I receive Input, I have a PHP file which posts it to JSON form already. But I need the ID part as identifier of the particular object. I tried all known ways, only ended up with messing up the code. Here's a detail explanation:

**JSON Code #1 [Which I'm getting]**

```
 [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "aaa",
            "doctor": "Doctor #1",
            "appointment": "13:03",
            "date": "1998-12-15"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "bbb",
            "doctor": "Doctor #2",
            "appointment": "14:14",
            "date": "2016-05-31"
    }
]
```

**JSON Code #2 [Desired, which I want]**

```
 [
         "1": {                            //The ID #1

            "name": "aaa",
            "doctor": "Doctor #1",
            "appointment": "13:03",
            "date": "1998-12-15"
        },
         "2": {                            //The ID #2
            "name": "bbb",
            "doctor": "Doctor #2",
            "appointment": "14:14",
            "date": "2016-05-31"
    }
]
```

**This is the PHP code I'm using to post the form data to the JSON File.**

```
          $filetxt = 'JSON URL'; 

          $formdata = array(

          'id'=> $_POST['id'],
          'name'=> $_POST['name'],
          'doctor'=> $_POST['doctor'],      
          'appointment'=> $_POST['appointment'],
          'date'=> $_POST['date'],
        );

        // path and name of the file
        $filetxt = 'PATH_OF_THE_FILE';

        $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

        if(file_exists($filetxt)) {      

          $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);


          $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        }        

        $arr_data[] = $formdata;        

        $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        if(file_put_contents('appointments.json', $jsondata))     
        include('URL');
        else include('URL2');
  }
```

Please help me with the PHP code part. Any way to optimize existing code would be appreciated too. Thanks ^.^

Comment: Explain what isn't working.

Comment: The ID comes as an element in the array, I need it as identifier of the array. I don't know the proper terms to use, sorry.

Comment: What you desire shall not be... you can't have associative arrays in JSON. It will be an object instead. `[ "1": {...}, ... ]` will be `{ "1": {...}, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your code like this:

```
$formdata = array(
  $_POST['id'] => array(
    'name'=> $_POST['name'],
    'doctor'=> $_POST['doctor'],      
    'appointment'=> $_POST['appointment'],
    'date'=> $_POST['date'],
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to create nested array for this :

Take a look :

```
$newArr[$_POST['id']] = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'doctor' => $_POST['doctor'],
            'appointment' => $_POST['appointment'],
            'date' => $_POST['date'],
            );
```